# I have a single defined primary key in my model, but Django throws multiple primary keys error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my code

```
class BsValuesTTM(models.Model):
        corpname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        co_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
        ACR = models.FloatField()
        Inventory = models.FloatField(null=True)
        CashCE = models.FloatField(null=True)
        CurrentAssets = models.FloatField()
        GrossPPE = models.FloatField()
        AccDepn = models.FloatField(null=True)
        NetPPE = models.FloatField()
        Intangibles = models.FloatField(null=True)
        NCA = models.FloatField()
        Assets = models.FloatField()
```

i only have a single primary key in my model, Django throws this error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple primary keys for table "Main_bsvaluesttm" are not allowed
```

I have changed the field for primary key, earlier it was corpname, and that field used to be a foreign key.
I am using Postgresql12 with Django.

Comment: Did you properly migrate your table changes

Comment: i followed the standard procedure of makegmigrations and migrate command, i did it after each change as i was testing the app while building it.

Comment: I have tried deleting this model and making another similar model, cant do that either

Comment: The issue wasnt fixed, had to start my project all over again, copy-pasted and it worked. Maybe the migrations are messed up.

Comment: Can you please post your resolution as an answer, and mark as resolved @samar2170?

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasnt fixed, had to start my project all over again, copy-pasted and it worked. The migrations are messed up.